# No results for terms in pdf

Tags: azure, search, bing, bing-api

Using the Bing Web Search API we are not getting any results for certain terms that we know are in a PDF file.

- We confirmed that the pdf is being indexed.
- Google does include the PDF in the results for the same term.
- We have tried v5.0 and v7.0 of the Bing Web Search API.
- Bing Webmaster tools doesn't provide any tools to address this problem (as far as we can tell)

Is there any documentation, guides or tips on how to find out why we are not getting any results and how to change that?

Thanks

**Update:**

We have found that the PDF file is not included in the results if the term is found towards the end of the file. The same PDF file is included in the results if the term is in the early pages. It seems the PDF file is only being partially indexed.

Answer (score 0):

For searching within pdf you can append the query with filetype:pdf. That should give results from pdf. Could you try and see if that works?

Comment: Thanks @ronak. My understanding is that filetype:pdf will limit the results to PDF files only. PDF files are included in the search results by default.